# Delphi MDIChild form flashes when opening in modal mode

Tags: delphi

I have a `MDIChild` form that I open as follows:

```
Application.CreateForm (TForm1, Form1);
```

exemple `MDIChild` form class

```
unit Unit1;  
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
end.
```

but sometimes I need this form in modal ... with some tips I adapted my code as follows to open it in modal mode:

```
Application.CreateForm (TForm1, Form1); 
Form1.FormStyle: = fsNormal; 
Form1.Visible: = False; 
Form1.Position: = poMainFormCenter; 
Form1.ShowModal;
```

that way it works, but it blinks until it shows on the screen ..

I would like to know if there is any way to not flash / show the form until you reach the `Form1.ShowModal` call;

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: No, switching form style from fsMdiChild to fsNormal triggers the window of the form to be recreated. Since your form is already visible (being an mdi child) it blinks. You have to adapt something different or change your design.

Comment: Why do you first change the style and then the visibility? I'd make the form hidden by default, create it, change the style to whichever you need, lastly show(modal) it.

Comment: @GolezTrol i'll try this..

Comment: You cannot hide an MdiChild as I stated in my comment. That's why you have *adapted* that code.

Comment: in the show method, it worked, but in the modal, I get the message Can not make a visible modal window, even showing the form on the screen, it is not modal.
as the change of style forces the recreation I believe that I will have to live with the blinks. :(

Comment: I found the solution on the portuguese stack: <https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/342261/formul%C3%A1rio-delphi-mdichild-pisca-ao-abrir-em-modo-modal/342264?noredirect=1#comment690122_342264>

Comment: For those that don't speak Portuguese, the solution proposed is essentially to create the Form with `FormStyle=fsNormal` and `Visible=False` by default (at design-time), and then manually switch it to `FormStyle=fsMDIChild` and `Visible=True` when it is not being shown modally.

Comment: Your question is stated as "how to modal show an mdi child without flicker". However the solution you say you found does not modal show a mdi child. You'd much better asked about the problem you were trying to solve, instead of asking how to implement your supposed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type
  TfrmManProduto = class(TForm)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; isModal: Boolean); reintroduce;
  end;

implemetation

TfrmManProduto.Create(AOwner: TComponent; isModal: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  Position := poMainFormCenter;

  if not (isModal) then
  begin
    FormStyle := fsMDIChild;
    Visible := True;
  end;
end;
```

Call MDIChild Style (Non-Modal)

```
frmManProduto := TfrmManProduto.Create(Application, False);
```

Call Normal Style (Modal)

```
frmManProduto := TfrmManProduto.Create(Application, True);
frmManProduto.ShowModal();
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the best solution, but it's at least pretty clear. You could even choose to pass the formstyle instead of a boolean, so the code is even more explicit, and you have the possibility to use the other styles as well.

Comment: @GolezTrol Great idea, pass the formstyle, even not having this need now, is functional for future needs.